# How to prove that the following function is monotonically increasing?

Tags: real-analysis

### $f(x) =  \frac{\sqrt{x}\int_a^1 e^{-xt} t^{\ b+1}~ \mathrm{d}t}{\int_a^1 e^{-xt} t^{\ b} ~\mathrm{d}t}:\ ]\ 0,+\infty\ [\ \to \mathbb{R} $

where  0 < a < 1   and  b > 0 .

By applying elementary rules of differentiation I can only prove that the function is monotonically increasing in $]\ 0,\frac{1}{1-a}\ ]$

But I need to prove that it is monotonically increasing in $]\ 0,+\infty\ [$

Comment: Looks like integrations by parts could be the way to go

Comment: I have already tried integration by parts but the attempt made wasn't successful.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the function should have that property? I inserted $a = 1/10$ and $b=1$ which is in the allowed range. Then WA gives this result:

$$
F(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x}\int_{0.1}^1 e^{-xt}t^2dt}{\int_{0.1}^1e^{-xt}t dt} = \frac{e^{9x/10}(x^2 + 20x + 200) - 100(x^2 + 2x + 2)}{100\sqrt{x}(e^{9x/10}(x+10) - 10(x+1))}.
$$

Plotting that function from $0$ to $20$ shows that it is first increasing but then decreasing again.

Comment: I was wrong because I thought the function was monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) =  \frac{\sqrt{x}\int_a^1 e^{-xt} t^{\ b+1}~ \mathrm{d}t}{\int_a^1 e^{-xt} t^{\ b} ~\mathrm{d}t}$$

Applying integration by parts
$$\int_a^1 e^{-xt} t^{\ b+1}dt = -\frac{1}{x}\int_a^1 e^{-xt} t^{\ b+1}dt + \frac{b+1}{x}\int_a^1 e^{-xt} t^{\ b}dt$$
Which means we can rewrite the functions as
$$f(x)=\frac{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\int_a^1 e^{-xt} t^{\ b+1}dt + \frac{b+1}{\sqrt{x}}\int_a^1 e^{-xt} t^{\ b}dt}{\int_a^1 e^{-xt} t^{\ b}dt}=\frac{f(x)}{-x}+\frac{b+1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
Now, we can solve for `f(x)`:
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x}(b+1)}{x+1}$$
Now, it is much easier to reason about the function.

And as the previous answer mentioned, and as [this graph shows](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(x)(1%2B1)%2F(x%2B1)), it is actually not monotonic for `b=1`

Comment: Uri, you are right when you say that the function is not monotonic, but f(x) is not equal to the expression that you obtained indeed you did not apply integration by parts correctly